# How can the zero ring be an initial object in the category of schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The spectrum of the zero ring is the empty set, right?  Prime ideals of a ring must be proper ideals.  So a morphism to a scheme $(X, \mathcal O_X)$ from the affine scheme corresponding to $0$ would include on the underlying spaces a continuous function $f$ from the empty set to $X$.  But there is no such function $f$.  So it seems like there wouldn't be any morphisms whatsoever from the affine scheme of the zero ring to the given scheme.

Comment: The zero ring is final in the category of rings. Its spectrum is initial in the category of schemes.

Comment: My bad, I corrected it.  But my question still applies

Comment: There's exactly one function *from* the empty set to any other set.

Comment: How can the empty set be an initial object though, when the morphisms are maps of sets?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein according to the equivalence of the category of rings and the opposite category of the category of affine schemes, we know it's spectrum is initial in the category of affine schemes.How do you get the result that initial in the category of schemes?

Comment: Let $X = \textrm{Spec}(0) = \emptyset$, and let $Y$ be any scheme.  Choose an open affine set $V$ of $Y$.  In general, a morphism of schemes $X \rightarrow Y$ whose set theoretic image is contained in $V$, corresponds bijectively to a morphism of schemes $X \rightarrow V$.  This is trivially satisfied for any morphism of schemes $X \rightarrow Y$, so we are reduced to the affine case.

Comment: @Jabin You're right that there is something to prove there. It shouldn't be too surprising that it's true though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The empty set is the initial object in the category of sets (and the category of topological spaces); that is, for any set $X$, there's a unique function $0 \to X$ from the empty set to $X$, namely the "empty function" (and if $X$ is a topological space then this function is continuous).

Here is what it does:

Similarly, the zero ring is the terminal object in the category of rings (and the category of commutative rings): for any ring $R$, there's a unique ring homomorphism $R \to 0$ sending everything to zero. The scheme result is a combination of these results.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: From your point, we can get the fact that the spectrum is an initial object in the category of affine schemes, so how to prove that in the category of schemes the result is also true?

Comment: @amWhy You rejected my proposed edit from $0\rightarrow X$ to $\emptyset \rightarrow X$, I would be glad if you could explain to me why. I assume I must have misunderstood something which caused me to the edit, thanks! Furthermore, I don't really see how the sentence "Here is what it does:" connects to the thing that is following, which leaves me a bit confused.